# All Desktop Icons Missing on Redirected Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-7, redirection

I'm running Windows 7 with a desktop location that is redirected to a Windows Server 2003 UNC location.  The rest of the machines in our environment are Windows XP and the icons show up fine.  On my machine, I'm missing all of my icons, including the Recycle Bin.  If I open up an explorer window and click on the "Desktop" icon in the left pane, all of the icons are there.  The issue seems to be that it can't actually display the contents of that folder on my actual desktop.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right Click on the Windows 7 Desktop -> Select "Arrange Icons By" -> Select "Show Desktop Icons"

Comment: How embarrassing!  The real question now is, why did this automatically uncheck itself on my machine and my colleague's machine (both Windows 7).  Is there some Group Policy setting I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity, do you have a "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDesktop" registry value?

If you do, what's it set to?